# Replacement for Microsoft Visual Modeler

Tags: visual-studio, uml

I have been using **Microsoft Visual Modeler** to draw UML class diagrams for my projects. The tool is a part of **Visual Studio 6**. Is there a way to import the existing diagrams into a more modern tool without redrawing them?

Visual Modeler is really a stripped-down demo version of Rational Rose software. It may be possible to import the diagrams in a current Rational Rose product, but I am looking for something cheap and simple. I only draw class diagrams and do not generate source code from them.

Answer (score 1):

My co-worker found 2 tools that import Rational Rose format, and he verified that they can import class diagrams from Visual Modeler. The tools are: **Visual Paradigm for UML** and **StarUML**. The first is a commercial tool that seems far more sophisticated than I need. **StarUML** is abandoned, but its new version, **White StarUML**, is currently supported. However, once I switch to this tool, I will not be able to migrate elsewhere, since it uses its own *.uml format (which is an XML) and does not export XMI.

Comment: If you ran the standard installer of WhiteStarUML and all Dlls were installed correctly you should see the File - Export - XMI menu command. Probably it is not perfect yet but the annoying crashing bug from StarUML was fixed.

Comment: @jszpilewski Thank you. I missed the export menu. It works (i.e. it creates an xml file; I don't have any tool at the moment to try to import them back).

Answer (score 0):

Importing between tools is in general a jester's errand, if not quite a fool's. There is a standardized interchange format (XMI) which most tools support, but it exists in more than a dozen versions and does not include diagram layouts. In other words, you might get the classes across to your new tool but your diagrams will stay where they are.

If you can live with that, and if you can get MS Visual Modeler to export an XMI version of the model, you should be able to get the guts of your models across to a modern tool like Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems, and then spend many a happy evening redrawing all the diagrams.

Comment: No, it seems that Visual Modeler does not support XMI. It can only save in 2 Rational Rose formats: *.mdl and *.ptl.

Comment: If your modelling tool doesn't support export to the standardized interchange format, you're pretty much stuck. You might want to check out TOOLBUS, a commercial model conversion tool. From the home page at http://www.reischmann.com, click Products, then look at the two PDFs for info on what it can convert (quite a lot); they also give you some hints as to which tools can import other tools' native formats.